# Nativescript camera module out of memory crash

Tags: image, caching, module, camera, nativescript

I need to take an image which size is huge 2048x1152 and it works first time but if I take second I get crash: "Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 377.....byte allocation with 148..... free bytes and 14MB until OOM"

My code follows these instructions from Nativescript documentation: https://docs.nativescript.org/hardware/camera

Question is. How and where can I somehow clear cache/whatever it is that hold my first image. Is the fault caused by camera module at all, is it on image module "var image = new imageModule.Image();"

Comment: My app also sometimes run out of memory, I would like to know if there are some basic rules how to prevent this in Nativescript.

Comment: I followed the steps from docs and the given code snippets, however I was unable to reproduce such an issue. Could you provide more info how to reproduce this problem or some sample code. In regard to that I think that this is not **NativeScript** problem.

Comment: Device is Samsung Galaxy J5 so it might take too much resources. Heres my exact code: 
cameraModule.takePicture({width: 2048, height: 1152, keepAspectRatio: true}).then(function (picture) {
        console.log("Taking picture...");
        image = new imageModule.Image();
        image.imageSource = picture;
        imageOutput.src = picture.android;

Comment: I made a little research and found possible solution for this issue. You should add in your `app/App_Resources/AndroidManifest.xml` file this line `android:largeHeap="true"` in the `application` open tag. It should look like this: `<application
  android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
  android:largeHeap="true">
`

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" seems to work so far. I've been able to take many images now.

Comment: Yep, this works but after taking image whole view comes very slow.

Comment: It does not work after all. It has something to do with camera module. I need to find a way to initialize it again. Clean it or something similar!